# Replacing value of one df column only in specific rows

Tags: r

I have vector *index* that corresponds to the rows of a df I want to modify for one specific column

```
index <- c(1,3,6)

dm <- one  two three four
       x    y    z    k
       a    b    c    r 
       s    e    t    f
       e    d    f    a
       a    e    d    r
       q    t    j    i
```

Now I want to modify column "three" only for rows 1, 3 and 6 replacing whatever value in it with "A".

Should I use *apply*?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `apply`. You could simply use the following:

```
dm$three[index] <- "A"
```